# How to record counter while not removing calculation in test code

Tags: c#

I have a method that increments every time the function is executed. However, from the recommendations I've been told that with compiler optimization turned on it ignores my calculation and just increments. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73875015/accurately-calculating-iops?noredirect=1#comment130444796_73875015) is the link to my previously asked question.

```
    private static void IntOp(object index)
{
    long op = 0;
    long intop = 0;
    while (!stop)
    {
        intop = (op + 1) - 10 * 2;
        op++;
    }

    operations[(int) index] = op;
}
```

How can I bypass this and still keep track of the number of times the operation has been performed?

Comment: The optimizer is only doing that because there's no discernable impact from your calculation (apart from taking time). Why does your calculation matter? Are you trying to do a benchmark to see how long it takes? Or did you intend to use `intop` somewhere?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior this is used to measure multithreaded performance of cpu cores by means of IOPS. So the benchmark is to measure how many IOP it can perform in a second. Could you give some recommendation to bypass this optimization?

Comment: You just have to do something to make it so the optimizer doesn't _know_ you're not using the result. For example, return the result (David's answer) or set the result to a field's value. Benchmarking is a tricky business, though, and you're most likely not measuring what you think you are. The `while(!stop)` branch and the `op++` probably takes almost as much time as your calculations do. Whatever you're using to stop after 1 second is probably not very precise. Thread management may be doing more work than each thread does. And so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can trivially fix this by returning `intop` at the end of your method.

```
private static long IntOp(object index)
{
    long op = 0;
    long intop = 0;
    while (!stop || intop < 100)
    {
        intop = (op + 1) - 10 * 2;
        op++;
    }

    operations[(int)index] = op;
    
    return intop;
}
```

Comment: That would be a good solution, however my goal is to measure how many operation it can execute for a given time frame(for example in 1 second) could you give a recommendation for this case?